# How to install Maxima CAS on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: software-installation, snap, 21.04

First I check if it is installed :

```
maxima
```

the result:

```
The assertion realpath(s,o) on line 471 of main.c in function mbin failed: Invalid argumentAborted (core dumped)
```

It is  [confirmed bug 1926225](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5913126.html) - .

So I try to [use snap](https://snapcraft.io/wxmaxima) :

```
sudo snap install wxmaxima
```

then check:

```
 snap find wx
```

The result :

```
Name               Version  Publisher       Notes  Summary
wxmaxima           17.04.1  peterpall       -      A nightly build of wxMaxima, a gui for Maxima, a full-featured CAS.
electronic-wechat  2.0      ubuntu-dawndiy  -      A better WeChat on macOS and Linux. Built with Electron.
sdlvnc             1.3.1    huedawn         -      SDL2 and wxWidgets VNC client.
stars              2.7jrc3  diddledan       -      STARS! The 4X Strategy game
growx              1.1      maumx2          -      GrowX: the Opensource Greenhouse monitoring App
skip               1.0.0    shadowxwarrior  -      SKIP Manager: Let's you skip package management
certbot-dns-inwx   2.1.3    oggy            -      INWX DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
rubber-band-async  0.1      andybulka       -      Rubberband wxPython app with wxasync clock
andy-testsnap-py   0.6      andybulka       -      Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap
```

Then try to run

```
 wxmaxima
```

the result:

```
(wxmaxima:10141): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

So maybe it need maxima :

```
sudo apt-get install maxima
```

the result:

```
maxima is already the newest version (5.44.0-2).
```

Is it possible to install Maxima CAS on Ubuntu 21.04 ?

----------------- edit ----------------

```
load(draw)
execvp failure when executing '/usr/bin/gcc -c -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/gcl-UR70am/gcl-2.6.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fsigned-char -pipe -fcommon -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-free -fno-PIE -fno-pie -fno-PIC -fno-pic -Wall -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I/usr/include/tirpc -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -I/usr/lib/gcl-2.6.12/unixport/../h  -O2  -c /home/a/.maxima/binary/5_44_0/gcl/GCL_2_6_12/share/draw/grcommon.c -o /home/a/.maxima/binary/5_44_0/gcl/GCL_2_6_12/share/draw/grcommon.o ': No such file or directory
loadfile: failed to load /usr/share/maxima/5.44.0/share/draw/draw.lisp
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
(%o17) "/home/a/Dokumenty/ijon/3006/a.mac"
(%i18) load(draw);
execvp failure when executing '/usr/bin/gcc -c -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/gcl-UR70am/gcl-2.6.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fsigned-char -pipe -fcommon -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-free -fno-PIE -fno-pie -fno-PIC -fno-pic -Wall -Wno-empty-body -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I/usr/include/tirpc -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -I/usr/lib/gcl-2.6.12/unixport/../h  -O2  -c /home/a/.maxima/binary/5_44_0/gcl/GCL_2_6_12/share/draw/grcommon.c -o /home/a/.maxima/binary/5_44_0/gcl/GCL_2_6_12/share/draw/grcommon.o ': No such file or directory

loadfile: failed to load /usr/share/maxima/5.44.0/share/draw/draw.lisp
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Is it a problem related with installation ? I have made [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maxima/+bug/1934595)

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error message (even down to the line number) when I try to start axiom in 22.04.3 (normal repository, not snaps - don't even have snap installed).  That suggests something deeper going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So both deb-packaged ([official](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/maxima) and from [“The maxima developers” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emaxima-developers/+archive/ubuntu/maxima-nightly/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=hirsute)) and [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/wxmaxima) versions of Maxima are broken on Ubuntu 21.04.
You have to remove Snap version with

```
snap remove wxmaxima
```

But `maxima` package from upcoming 21.10 works normally. You can install it with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/maxima/maxima_5.44.0-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install wxmaxima ./maxima_5.44.0-3_amd64.deb
```

and use as it was planned.

Comment: Nice answer. About scientific computing: I recently tried Manjaro, and found that diagonalization in Octave is much faster there (maybe due to the latest version of openblas), and also, bugs like these get fixed quite soon.